# Unable to get available content between dates from office 365 management api

Tags: office365api

I'm using the [Office 365 Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) to get available content (audits) between dates but I keep getting events from the last 24 hours.

This is the url I'm using:

`/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Exchange&amp;startTime=2017-08-11&amp;endTime=2017-08-12`

I tried using all date formats listed in the documentation

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

I also tried switching the start and end (from the later to the earlier).

Another thing I tried is giving a range of less than 24 hours in the last 24 hours.

But I still get the entire last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

So although the Microsoft documentation shows an escaped & char the correct url is with only the & char like this:

/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Exchange&startTime=2017-08-11&endTime=2017-08-12